# Best rotation of centered equilateral triangle in square for maximum distance between triangle cornes and square edges

Tags: geometry

A question that occurred to me during the construction of a cat tree.

I have an equilateral triangle and a square with the side length of the square bigger than that of the triangle. The triangle shall be placed inside the square, so that the center points of the two overlap.

With this conditions, I can place the triangle, so that one side of the triangle is parallel to one side of the square. When I rotate the triangle 30°, I end up with another side of the triangle parallel to one side of the square, which basically is the same configuration. Since the center point is fixed, I figured that I can only vary the rotation of the triangle in a range of [0°, 30°).

Now I want to maximize the sum of the distances of the three triangle corners to the respective nearest point on an edge of the square.

How do I calculate the optimal rotation? I struggle with setting up the equations for the corner distances and my geometry knowledge sadly ends at this point as it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

If you do not require the triangle and square to have the same center point, you would be looking for the orientation where the axis-aligned bounding box of an equilateral triangle is a square.  This happens whenever you rotate the triangle so that two of the sides are at an angle of $15° = \frac{\pi}{12}\text{ radians}$ with the axes, and the third is at $45°$ to both axes.

If you do require the triangle and square to have the same center point, then you'll notice that between $-15°$ and $+15°$ (of one side being parallel to the horizontal axis), each triangle vertex is closest to the same edge within this range, with two vertices being at the same distance from their respective edges at $\pm 15°$, and the third vertex at equal distances from two different edges.  In essence, then, too, rotating the triangle so that two of the sides are at an angle of $15° = \frac{\pi}{12}\text{ radians}$ with the axes, and the third at $45°$ to both axes, minimises the distance between triangle vertices and the square edges.

Thus, whether you fix the center of the triangle or not, the rotation is $\pm 15° = \pm \frac{\pi}{12}\text{ radians}$ from when one of the sides is parallel to the square edges.